# InfoPath 2013 / SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, infopath, error

I have a problem with a customized Workflow Task Form. It generates the following error:

> "The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has
>   exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server
>   administrator. Form elements, such as drop-down lists, may be blank."

In this Task Library we have currently about 465 items. Normally I would say this isn't a big deal, but since a week we've seen above error coming up. We changed the Data Connection Response Size to 4500KB. It didn't help, so we changed it to 5000KB. This worked out.

I've attached the form as an attachment.

[image]

Does anyone have a clue... since it should not happed on these kind of forms...

I think that it should not occur when there is that less information in the list or on the form.

Answer (score 1):

For some rhyme or reason, SharePoint is querying content that brings back a lot of data, either through a drop-down list, or multiple lookups. There may be a data connection that doesn't have a proper filter, is querying a big list, or otherwise grabs a lot of data that it shouldn't.

If your InfoPath form works by increasing the Data Connection Response Size, I'd say that isn't out of supported practice, so that's ok. But I would still look at those data connections and see if they are set and filter correctly.